# Setting up system for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS only

Tags: grub2, uefi

I have a laptop. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04, and perhaps openSuse at a later time. I am looking online regarding bios configuration. I have option of UEFI/Legacy/Both. I have no interest in Windows. Where are steps to take to install Ubuntu 16.04 and whether disabling UEFI would be beneficial? Will all hardware work on laptop if boot in legacy? 
The system has SSD drive.

Comment: Please clarify if you want to remove or keep Windows. Next, choose between: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid0LaJ-rbXAhWIo6QKHZ2PC0IQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tecmint.com%2Finstall-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot%2F&usg=AOvVaw0yZoAacyuXjqo8jscBbERZ    and   https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid0LaJ-rbXAhWIo6QKHZ2PC0IQFgg9MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Flts%2Finstallation-guide%2Findex.html&usg=AOvVaw0ygse9rejX8HxIvhA0sI2P

Comment: @WillemK He precised he has no interest in Windows :)

Comment: @Doudou: yes, I did read that but I merely give the OP both options; install along side Windows or a single install. I have seen too many posts of people saying something like "I tried Ubuntu and want Windows back".

Comment: No windows. Google.com - If you have nothing to contribute don't. I researched this problem, and am getting either conflicting or incomplete information. I only know that if I want Windows, from what I have read,  I must have UEFI.  I know nothing of why UEFI would be needed for a linux only boot and if choosing legacy may break or flake hardware/firmware.